# Why this constant coefficient is used to represent the number of the electric lines of force?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, mathematical-physics

[image]

The point charge has been placed at the origin in Cartesian coordinate system.

The number of the electric lines of force which comes out from the point charge is $\frac{q}{\epsilon_{0}}$

The solid angle of the green cone is $\omega=2 \pi (1-\cos(\theta))$

The description states that the number of electric lines of force which penetrate the blue bottom(surface) is $$\frac{q}{\epsilon_{0}}\frac{\omega}{4\pi}$$

How $\frac{\omega}{4\pi}$ comes from?

By the way, from the definition of solid angle ,needless to say that I think that the shape of the solid angle must be a subsurface of the sphere not a plane ,like above diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total flux through a surface containing the point charge is $\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$. (This is Guass's law and if you have not head of flux before it is the amount of electric field lines passing through the surface). Because situation is spherically symmetric, and the solid angle of the whole surface is $4 \pi$  the fraction of flux through your surface is $ \frac{\omega}{4 \pi} \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$. Note that this result does not depend on the surface being a subset of a sphere. The solid angle is the area you get when you project a surface onto the unit sphere and this works for any surface